# "Windows cannot load the locally stored profile"

Tags: windows-xp, login, windows-domain

I have been getting the error described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812339, but as I am logging in with a domain account creating a new local account is not a valid solution. I would also not expect my profile to exist in the local "Documents and Settings" folder, since it is being stored on the PDC.

This seems to happen consistently when I try to log onto the network from a cold boot, but after logging in with the "temporary profile" and then logging out, I can log in normally and everything works fine.

Anyone experienced this error in a Windows domain environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using roaming profiles. I would rename you local account `c:\documents and settings\cmdrmoozy[.old]` and do the same on the server side.  log in again (creating a "clean profile) and begin moving the data back over from your ".old" account. *TIP* It might also be a good idea to delete any related profiles from the registry before logging in after renaming your account ".old". The profile list can be found at `HKLM\software\microsoft\windows NT\profilelist`.